# Box-sizing or media query creating whitespace?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Working on my Rails app and I'm trying to get my posts to be 3 a row like this. (This only happens if I comment-out box-sizing, -moz and -webkit; but I'm left with a horizontal scroll bar with my side nav overlapping my posts image)[image: ![Pic 1]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qk71.png)

But for some reason it's 2 row with extra white space [image: Pic 2]

When I'm in fullscreen it works...When I'm not in fullscreen mode [image]

Are my breakpoints wrong or would it have something to do with box-sizing: border-box?

**Here is my posts.scss file**

```
/*  Main  */
 .main{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: 300px;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;     
 box-sizing: border-box;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 55;
 background: #f6f6f6;
 clear: both;}

/*  Home/portfolio  */
 .main .work{
 display: block;
 //width: 33.33%;   
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;}

 .main .work .media{
 width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;}

 .main .work .caption{
 //position: absolute;           
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #ffffff;
 opacity: 0;}


 .main .work a:hover .caption{
 opacity: 1;}


 .work .caption .work_title{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -40px;}

 .main .work .caption h1{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 max-width: 90%;
 padding: 20px 0;
 z-index: 77;
 color: #454545;
 font-family: "raleway-regular", arial;
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: .5px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbbbb;
 border-top: 1px solid #bfbbbb;}

 img.post {
 width: 372px;
 height: 380px;}
```

**And the responsive code I'm working with**

```
@media (max-width:1099px){

 header{
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 100px;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
 }
 header .logo{
     margin: 40px 0 0 30px;
     float: left;
 }
 header .footer{
     display: none;
 }
 header #menu_icon,
 header .close_menu{
     float: right;
     margin: 30px 30px 0 0;
 }

 header nav{
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 9999;
 }

 header nav ul{
     list-style: none;
     display: none;
     position: relative;
 }
 header nav ul li a{
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 30px 0;
     text-align: center;
     color: #454545;
     font-family: "raleway-regular", arial;
     font-size: 14px;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-top: 1px solid #f7f5f5;
     background: #fff;
 }
 header nav ul li a:active{
     background: #f7f5f5;
 }
 #menu_icon,
 .close_menu,
 .show_menu{
     display: block;
 }
 .show_menu{
     display: block;
 }

 .main .work{
     width: 50%;
 }
 .main{
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     padding-left: 0;
 }
 #map{
     margin: 0!important;
 }}

 @media (max-width:550px){
  .main .work{
     width: 100%;
 }}
```

Thank you for any help that you're abe to give me!

**UPDATE**

**My index.html.erb file**

```
<%= render "partials/header" %>
 <section class="main clearfix">
  <div class="work">
   <a href="">
    <img src="" class="media" alt=""/>
     <h1 class="current-category"><%= params[:category] %></h1>
       <% if @posts.count == 0 %>

         <h1>There are no Post currently in this category</h1>

       <% else %>

         <% @posts.each do |post| %>
           <a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>">
             <%= image_tag post.post_img.url(:post_index), class:  "post" %>
           </a>
         <% end %>

       <% end %>
   <div class="caption">
     <div class="work_title">
     </div>
   </div>
 </a>
```

**My _header.html.erb file just incase**

```
<header>
<div class="logo">
 <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" title="" alt=""/></a>
</div><!-- end logo -->


<div id="menu_icon"></div>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html" class="selected">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#"><%= link_to "Add Post", new_post_path %></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav><!-- end navigation menu -->
</header>
```

Comment: can you also provide your html structure ??

Comment: Try to set your link's font-size: 0. White-space often appears around images elements because of this property.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion @Ilya B. but that didn't move the post it's still the same as my second pic.But I'll keep plugging away there's something simple I'm missing.

Comment: I cant seem to recreate the scenario in JSFiddle...

Comment: Hey @Andrew thanks for trying. I think I have something wrong in one of my rails files and not actually the scss stylesheet. So I'll just have to keep messing around with it. I know it's something simple I'm missing lol. Anyway thank you again for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to resolve this is to make sure you're not using `relative` or `absolute` positioning - you'd be best keeping your `img` elements as [`display: inline-block;`](http://jsfiddle.net/2hwjvemL/1/):

```css
.portfolio { display: block }
.portfolio img {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/200" /></a>
    <a href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/200" /></a>
    <a href="/"><img src="http://placehold.it/200" /></a>
</div>
```

One of the issues with this is that `inline-block` is treated as `inline`, and has some automatic `margin` applied to the elements. You get rid of it by [using negative margin](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

`box-sizing` simply defines the size of the element. You'll still get alignment issues regardless of how the element's size is calculated.

---

Your code is pretty haphazard, why are you calling `<a href="">` and then embedding *another* link inside it?

I'd do the following:

```
<%= render "partials/header" %>

<section class="main clearfix">
<div class="work">
   <h1 class="current-category"><%= params[:category] %></h1>
   <% if @posts.count == 0 %>
      <h1>There are no Post currently in this category</h1>
   <% else %>
      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <%= link_to post do >
           <%= image_tag post.post_img.url(:post_index), class:  "post" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>


.main .work a.post img {
   display: inline-block
   margin: 0 0 0 -3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The code is pretty haphazard, a friend and I was both working on it. I was doing the backend and he was the front. He's been in having some problem in life so I've been left with all of his work there is a lot to clean up lol. Anyway, thank you for the help and link. I'll be reading up more on Inline blocks and box-sizing just in general.